# Difficulty debugging a Node.js memory Leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, memory-leaks, sails.js

I manage a Node.js + Sails.js (a Node.js-based MVC framework) server that tipically occupies ~65MB of RAM. After opening a certain page, the memory usage increases drastically, until it freezes the PC or throws a FATAL ERROR with a heap related error. In the second screenshot we can note an array emerging and occupying a large portion of memory. I found an object that is really present in the code (that purple providerinformation in the inferior part). But it doesn't tell much, it's a just a model name and page name. In an older version of the code that is running on prd server it doesn't happen so I don't think it is caused by Sails, since I didn't update sails (at least not in package.json) and I didn't find memory leak issues in my node version (the server runs an older version). How can I proceed?
Notes:

- Even deactivating scheduled services and not making new requests the memory usage increases in the same behavior
- The problem only starts after reaching a specific page
- The problem happens when I connect to dev db (that is populated with hundreds of tuples while my local server has very few)
  Error message:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [11733:0x563472f0af10]   182853 ms: Scavenge 2037.3 (2046.9) -> 2034.8 (2047.6) MB, 8.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.137, current mu = 0.087) allocation failure
> [11733:0x563472f0af10]   182873 ms: Scavenge 2038.1 (2047.6) -> 2035.5 (2048.1) MB, 8.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.137, current mu = 0.087) allocation failure
> [11733:0x563472f0af10]   182894 ms: Scavenge 2038.7 (2048.1) -> 2036.2 (2056.9) MB, 9.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.137, current mu = 0.087) allocation failure

> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 0x27d5da31b9a1 
> 0: builtin exit frame: stringify(this=0x27d5da30b729 ,2,0x29315ef004b1 ,0x19341927f741 <JSArray[124555]>,0x27d5da30b729 )
>
> ```
> 1: json [0xa7e9a32a209] [/home/user/Desktop/tog/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/response.js:231] [bytecode=0x1d029d7bc129 offset=156](this=0x21ddafea9a29 <ServerResponse map = 0x196796078bf9>,0x19...
> ```
>
> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
> 1: 0x7fa5b026c3cc node::Abort() [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 2: 0x7fa5b019c67c  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 3: 0x7fa5b0641e2a v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 4: 0x7fa5b06421e4 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 5: 0x7fa5b07f4509  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 6: 0x7fa5b0804dc6 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 7: 0x7fa5b0805c12 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 8: 0x7fa5b0806070 v8::internal::Heap::CollectAllGarbage(int, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 9: 0x7fa5b07b5ee8 v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 10: 0x7fa5b08fb74b v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 11: 0x7fa5b0900464 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 12: 0x7fa5b0900c9f v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 13: 0x7fa5b0901e2c v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Stringify(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 14: 0x7fa5b0901ebf v8::internal::JsonStringify(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 15: 0x7fa5b06ef2c6 v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> 16: 0x7fa5b112ec79  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.72]
> [1]    11733 IOT instruction (core dumped)  node --inspect app

[image: Screenshot from 2022-08-30 15-30-45]
[image: Screenshot from 2022-08-30 15-34-19]

**Node version**: v12.22.9
**Sails version** *(sails)*: 0.12.14
**ORM hook version** *(sails-hook-orm)*: 1.0.9
**Sockets hook version** *(sails-hook-sockets)*: 0.13.11
**DB adapter & version** *(e.g. sails-mysql@5.55.5)*: sails-postgresql@0.11.4
**Skipper adapter & version** *(e.g. skipper-s3@5.55.5)*: skipper@0.7.6

Ohh, and I don't want to ~export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192", as long as I understand, eventually the heap size will reach the new limit